# Is currentUser specific to device

Tags: parse-platform

is currentUser on parse specific to devise?  When the user is logged in and cached as the currentUser, it is only for that device he is using that he will be automatically logged in, is that correct?

My app sets currentUser in appdelegate, so if a user A logged in on Device A, and he is still cached on parse server, would user B who launched my app on device B be logged in as user A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
Yes, it's specific to device. It is only for that device that the user is logged in, so if User A opens the app on another device, they will have to log in again.

2.
If User A logs in on Device A, it will not affect User B on Device B. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

When one of your users logs in, that session is only cached on that device, so yes, your first statement is correct. I am unsure about the second part because I don't know what you mean by "My app sets currentUser in app delegate". Can you post your code?

Your code to login a user should take from user input, their specific username and password combination. When you login a user, you shouldn't use constants, then the same user will be logged in on every device.

Answer (score 0):

For every device that a user has logged in he will be automatically be logged in when launching the application.